# Maximize the mutual permutation disparity

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

I am trying to work on a problem that needs me to find the top-k most disparate permutations for a n-tuple (hence n! possible choices). The disparity measure between two permutations I'm thinking of is $\Delta = \sum_{i=1}^n \left| p_i - q_i \right|$ where $p$ and $q$ are the position vectors of the said permutations. Thus I need to find $k$ permutations which maximize the sum of their mutual $k*(k-1)/2$ disparity measures.

Does there exist a non-bruteforce methods for approaching this ? Randomized methods would also be great.

Thanks